# Issues running react app due to babel-eslint

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, babel-eslint

So for my MIT online class they told us to down load this react app and run npm install to install dependencies and then npm run start to start the app. But when I did the npm install there was a bunch of deprecated errors:
[Terminal errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuLZl.png)
and when I tried to do npm run start I got the following errors:
[NPM RUN START TIPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTLQ3.png)
[NPM errors after run start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oU9P.png)
I followed all the tips to correct it but nothing worked.

This may also be important info. This class is kind of old so they told us in the beginning of the project to use node 14. I used the n 14 command to use this version for this project since nvm will not download due to errors also. I tried to do the npm install and run start on both the newest version of node and the older one and got the same errors.

This is the package.json code. It makes no sense to me because babel-eslint was never on the package.json.

```js
{
  "name": "dockerize-me",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Something does not add up. Are you sure the `package.json` provided is the actual one from your project? Or did you change that `package.json`  trying to fix it? Are there any `devDependencies`?
 
There are a bunch of dependencies (@hapi, core-js, ...) that are not listed in that `package.json` but are installed.


can you run `npm ls babel-eslint`? This should show a dependency tree and tell you where or which package installed `babel-eslint@9`.

Comment: Do as suggested by cra, you should be fine. If the error still exist even after that it mostly (as you would already know) because there exist different version of babel-eslint, you could run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` which would install the different version and resolve it properly